# How to access attributes of php object inside a array of php objects from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array of php objects. Inside a javascript function I want to access attributes of an object in the array. If I `json_encode` the whole array it shows these attributes are `undefined`. How can I do this. I new to PHP.

**PHP Code:**

```php
$_SESSION['objArray'] = $objArray;
```

**Javascript Code:**

```js
const objArray = <?php echo json_encode(($_SESSION['objArray'])) ?>;
```

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Can you paste some code you have written?

Comment: I edited the question to show the code. Solution for this would be a big help. $objArray is the array with php objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need to encode your array to JSON so it can be usable by a JavaScript client.

As you mentioned, you have instances of particular classes in your array, so simple JSON encoding won't work for sure.

Here, PHP comes with the [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/jsonserializable) interface. You will have to implement this interface on your classes. Let's take a `Foo` example:

```php
class Foo implements JsonSerializable
{
  private $thing;

  public function __construct($thing)
  {
    $this->thing = $thing;
  }

  public function jsonSerialize()
  {
    return [
      'thing' => $this->thing,
    ];
  }
}
```

[Here](https://3v4l.org/c9UeF) is an example of the above code snippet. As you can see, now you can create an instance of `Foo`, embed it into an array or whatever, and JSON-encode it with your own representation:

```php
$foo = new Foo('something');
echo json_encode(['foo' => $foo]);

// {"foo": {"thing": "something"}}
```

Outputting this into an inline JavaScript block would work similar to what you wrote:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
const obj = "<?php echo json_encode(($_SESSION['objArray'])) ?>;";
</script>
```

Comment: I tried but this was displayed "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I'm relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

Store php array into javascript variable,

**Example Value:** *(example array inside `$_SESSION['objArray']`)*

```php
$_SESSION['objArray'] = array(
    'name' => 'foo',
    'email' => 'foo@gmail.com',
    'age' => 30
);
```

**Convert object to array:** (optional) *(if you have object value inside `$_SESSION['objArray']`)*

```php
$_SESSION['objArray'] = json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION['objArray']), true);
```

**Solution:** *(assign in to javascript variable `objArray`)*

```js
<script>
    const objArray = "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['objArray']); ?>";
    console.log(objArray);
</script>
```

**Console Output:**

```js
{"name":"foo","email":"foo@gmail.com","age":30}
```

---

**Explanation:** `json_encode` function will convert array in to a `json` string and javascript will consider it as a string and at assignment time it need to cover with quotation ether its `'` or `"`.

Hope this help.

Comment: The array you have given is of key value pairs but the array that I have consists of objects of a particular class. And those objects have attributes inside them. What I need is to access those attributes

Comment: I have updated answer, you can convert your object to array using `json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION['objArray']), true);`

Comment: @turivishal that is sketchy though

Comment: Hi @victor, I am not getting you, can you please explain.

Comment: @turivishal  I tried this method but I could not get it to work it showed in the javascript objArray as a 2D array , but the inside array didn't have the attributes

Comment: Can you please add your code in your question..if possible.

Comment: @turivishal by doing `json_decode(json_encode())` you do not get control over your objects are serialized. You rely on PHP's behavior when using this. I would honestly call it a *hack*. Apart from that, serializing and deserializing JSON are pretty slow operations, so we should not do one just to reverse it then.

Comment: Okay @victor, thanks for your information, yes we can say its hack.